# Using r, readShapeSpatial fails with simplified mapshaper.org shape

Tags: shapefile, r, mapping

So I'm mapping out the postal regions of my country and it's an enormous, 5.4million row dataframe.  I don't need every single little twist and turn of the boundries, so I was super excited to discover [mapshaper.org](http://mapshaper.org).  Seemed easy enough, I just threw my .shp file into it, and it spit back a file 10% of the size!  Excellent!

Nope..  now it doesn't play with readShapeSpatial...  Hopefully I won't need to provide the shapefile (i can track it down if that parts really necessary)

Original code, works:

```
canada.shp <- readShapeSpatial("canada", verbose=TRUE, delete_null_obj=TRUE)
```

New map, doesn't:

```
canada.shp <- readShapeSpatial("simplecanada", verbose=TRUE, delete_null_obj=TRUE)
Shapefile type: Polygon, (5), # of Shapes: 1621
Error in `rownames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5",  : 
  attempt to set 'rownames' on an object with no dimensions
In addition: Warning message:
In .Map2PolyDF(Map, IDs = IDvar, proj4string = proj4string, force_ring = force_ring,  :
  Null objects with the following indices deleted: 895
```

traceback() reveals:

```
4: stop("attempt to set 'rownames' on an object with no dimensions")
    3: `rownames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", 
   "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", 
   "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", 
   "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", 
   "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47", "48", "49", 
   "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58", "59", "60", (ETC!!!!)
2: .Map2PolyDF(Map, IDs = IDvar, proj4string = proj4string, force_ring = force_ring, 
       delete_null_obj = delete_null_obj, retrieve_ABS_null = retrieve_ABS_null)
1: readShapePoly("simplecanada", 
       verbose = TRUE, delete_null_obj = TRUE)
```

Comment: And with `readOGR()` of the `rgdal` package?

Comment: @mythstified Can you provide a link to your data, in order to reproduce the issue, and investigate a solution? thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am wondering why he bothered to send the data to an external service at all, while sitting in front of a powerful tool like R?

For simplifying shapes, you can e.g. use **gSimplify** from **rgeos** package.

See https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/151941/8202 for correct handling of the output.

Comment: Better yet, use `rmapshaper::ms_simplify` to get the same functionality as that website, although it wasn't around when OP posted this question. gSimplify doesn't preserve between-polygon topology, which leaves it with a pretty narrow range of acceptable use cases. And that website is pretty great for getting a sense of how simplifying algorithms work - I'd use it to pick appropriate tolerance values, for sure.

Answer (score -1):

Is it possible you are actually reading a point file, not polygon file? In that case, you might try  instead:

```
readShapePoints("simplecanada", verbose=TRUE, delete_null_obj=TRUE)
```