# writeOGR with a spatialpolygon simplified by gSimplify

Tags: shapefile, r, simplify, rgdal

I'm using `gSimplify` (rgeos package) to simplify the geometries of a shapefile. The funcion works good, but now I can't write the output in a new shapefile.
I tried some ways:

```
writeOGR(simplyshape, file, driver="ESRI Shapefile", layer='test')
```

I get

> obj must be a SpatialPointsDataFrame, SpatialLinesDataFrame or
>       SpatialPolygonsDataFrame

and with:

```
writePolyShape(simplyshape, file)
```

I get:

> Error: is(x, "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame") is not TRUE

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Coerce your object to the appropriate `Spatial*DataFrame`-class (Points/Lines/Polygons), e.g. for `SpatialPolygons` using `as(x, "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame" )`:

```
R> l <- readWKT("LINESTRING(0 7,1 6,2 1,3 4,4 1,5 7,6 6,7 4,8 6,9 4)")
R> x1 <- gSimplify(p, tol=10)
R> class(x1)
[1] "SpatialPolygons"
attr(,"package")
[1] "sp"
R> x2 <- as(x, "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame")
R> class(x2)
[1] "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame"
attr(,"package")
[1] "sp"
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to convert your `SpatialPolygons` class to a `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` class.  For example:

```
require(rgdal)
require(rgeos)

# Read shapefile
shp = 'C:/temp/myshp.shp'
myshp = readOGR(shp, layer = basename(strsplit(shp, "\\.")[[1]])[1])

# Read shapefile attributes
df = data.frame(myshp)

# Simplify geometry using rgeos
simplified = gSimplify(myshp, tol = 1000, topologyPreserve=FALSE)

# Create a spatial polygon data frame (includes shp attributes)
spdf = SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(simplified, df)

# Write to shapefile
writeOGR(spdf, layer = 'myshp_simplified', 'C:/temp', driver="ESRI Shapefile")
```