# Writing SpatialLines objects in R

Tags: shapefile, r, maps

I used the function landgenreport from the package popgenreport in R to create an object result.

This object is a list with various objects including SpatialLines class objects. I am trying to write these lines to a file readable in GIS software such as ArcGIS or QGIS. The problem is that I can not find a way to do that. I've tried several functions from several packages and I always get an error.

```
library(raster)
library(rgdal)
library(sp)
library(maptools)  

results$leastcost$paths[[1]][[78]] #this is the specific SpatialLine
linha78<-results$leastcost$paths[[1]][[78]]
writeSpatialShape(linha78,"linha78.shp")
Error in writeSpatialShape(results$leastcost$paths[[1]][[78]],"linha78.shp"):x is aSpatialLinesobject, not a compatible Spatial*DataFrame
```

So I tried to transform the SpatialLines object to a SpatialDataFrame and got another error message.

```
x = data.frame(linha78)
Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE) : 
cannot coerce class "structure("SpatialLines", package = "sp")" to a data.frame
```

I've tried a lot a different possible solutions I read here and there, but it simply does not work. As such:

[writeOGR with a spatialpolygon simplified by gSimplify](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/151924/writeogr-with-a-spatialpolygon-simplified-by-gsimplify)

[How to export a dataset with "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame" as a shapefile](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/162019/how-to-export-a-dataset-with-spatialpolygonsdataframe-as-a-shapefile)

http://r-sig-geo.2731867.n2.nabble.com/Saving-a-spatial-point-object-into-a-shapefile-td5704759.html

Comment: Can you link to the solutions you have tried?

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/151924/writeogr-with-a-spatialpolygon-simplified-by-gsimplify

http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/162019/how-to-export-a-dataset-with-spatialpolygonsdataframe-as-a-shapefile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using [maptools](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/maptools/maptools.pdf) it says not to specify the extension ".shp"

Try:

```
results$leastcost$paths[[1]][[78]] #this is the line
linha78<-results$leastcost$paths[[1]][[78]]
writeSpatialShape(linha78,"linha78")
```

**Update:**
You need to create a SpatialLinesDataFrame in order to write it out. In the OP you just created a data.frame (not spatial). id=1:length creates data.frame that has rows 1 to the length of your linha78. Try typing `length(linha78` into the console, it should give you the number of rows for linha78 :

```
results$leastcost$paths[[1]][[78]] #this is the line
linha78<-results$leastcost$paths[[1]][[78]]
df<-SpatialLinesDataFrame(linha78, data.frame(id=1:length(linha78)))
writeOGR(df, dsn="c:/Ouputs" ,layer="linha78",driver="ESRI Shapefile")
```

Comment: I got an error.
    Error in writeSpatialShape(linha78, "linha78") : 
  x is aSpatialLinesobject, not a compatible Spatial*DataFrame

Comment: when you run `class(linha78)` what is the output?

Comment: > linha78
class       : SpatialLines 
features    : 1 
extent      : -40.59125, -39.80625, -20.37875, -19.08125  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +proj=merc +units=m +ellps=WGS84

Comment: It worked just fine. Thank you very much! One question, what does the id=1 do?

Comment: I updated the answer to include more details, if this worked for you please accept it as the answer! Basically, you need to create an empty spatial dataframe that is the same length of the object to create a spatiallinedataframe.

Comment: Nice answer. And i suppose once SpatialLinesDataFrame is created, writeSpatialShape() will also work.

Comment: @Kazuhito I think so, I think OGR is better in this instance because it includes the projection.

Comment: Great value adding. How I wish I could upvote twice...